# Regular expression to match page number groups

Tags: regex, vba

I need a regular expression to match page numbers as found in common programs.

These usually take the form 1-5,3,5,1-9 for example.

I have a regular expression `(\d+-\d+)?,(\d+-\d+?)*` which I need help to refine.

As can be seen here [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UjLzwY/1) I am matching commas and missing numbers entirely.

What I need is to match `1-5` as group 1, `3` as group 2, `5` as group 3 and `1-9` as group 4 without matching any commas.

Any help is appreciated.  I will be using this in VBA.

Comment: Why don't you match 4 capturing groups? https://regex101.com/r/UjLzwY/1

Comment: Have you tried this `([0-9-]+)`

Comment: Do you want to have covered more than the case `'a-b,c,d,e-f'` or just that fixed structure?

Comment: Why not simply split on comma ',', that should give you an array with 4 elements.

Comment: Probably because you want to match this in a huge string with a lot more commas.

Comment: @ThiagoDaAnunciação tried your suggestion with limited success as it picked up spaces albeit I could remove these before running the regex!!

Comment: @DavidWierichs no not this structure exactly.  This was just an example.  It could be any number of numbers separated by dashes and delimited by commas with other numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me - am I missing something?

```
Sub Pages()
    
    Dim re As Object, allMatches, m, rv, sep, c As Range, i As Long
    
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Pattern = "(\d+(-\d+)?)"
    re.ignorecase = True
    re.MultiLine = True
    re.Global = True
    
    For Each c In Range("B5:B20").Cells 'for example
        c.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 10).ClearContents 'clear output cells
        i = 0
        If re.test(c.Value) Then
            Set allMatches = re.Execute(c.Value)
            For Each m In allMatches
                i = i + 1
                c.Offset(0, i).Value = m
            Next m
        End If
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Using `1-5` as an example, your regex pattern does pick up on a sub-groups of `1` & `-5` but despite this it does pick up on the full match of `1-5` so this is what you reflected in your code and appears to give me what I am after.  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `-\d+` part optional, since you don't always have ranges. And the comma between each range should be part of the second group with the `*` quantifier, so you can match a single range with no comma after it.

```
\d+(-\d+)?(,\d+(-\d+)?)*
```

This will match the string that contains all the ranges. To get an array of individual ranges without the commas, do a second match in this string:

```
\d+(-\d+)?
```

Use the VBA function for getting an array of all matches of a regexp (sorry, I don't know VBA, so can't provide the specific syntax).

Comment: Unless you know the maximum number of ranges, you can't get each into its own capture group. A quantified group only captures one of the matches.

Comment: This is just for matching the entire set of ranges, not for capturing each individual range.

Comment: Use this to find the whole set of ranges. Then do a separate match to extract each range in the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, capturing a dynamic number of groups will not work. You can pre-specify the format / number of groups to be matched, or you can catch the repeated groups as one and split them afterwards.
If you know the format, just do

```
(\d+(?:-\d+)?)(?:,)(\d+(?:-\d+)?)(?:,)(\d+(?:-\d+)?)(?:,)(\d+(?:-\d+)?)
```

which of course is not very neat.
If you want the flexible structure, match the first group and all the rest as a second and then split the latter by the delimiter `','` in whichever language.

```
(\d+(?:-\d+)?)((?:(?:,)(\d+(?:-\d+)?))*)
```

Comment: You're correct, a repeating subpattern will keep overwriting the capture group, so it wouldn't work.  Another option is to search globally and only look for whole matches, but I just have too many questions about what's valid or not.